# parskip messes with the vertical space between a theorem and its proof

Tags: thmtools, parskip, parindent

Not sure why, but I usually prefer no `parindent`, so I have to make up with `parskip`.  Perhaps its a bad decision, but I usually find it easier to read that way, especially online.

However, I recently noticed that with these settings, there's a vertical space between a theorem and its proof which is a bit too large to my taste.  This is seen especially when there's a sequence of theorems and proofs, and these extra spaces "group" it wrong - a proof seems closer to the theorem below it.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=thm,parent=section]{theorem}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1ex

\begin{document}
Some normal text.

Another paragraph.
\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Its proof.
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
Another theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Another proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Removing the parskip/parindent definitions produces this:

[image]

Theorems look better, but the paragraphs above (naturally) have no vertical space between them.

I can probably hack the proof theorem with `thmtools`, but I was wondering if this is the way to go (from a technical point of view, but also from a design point of view).

What do you think?

Comment: the `proof` environment in `amsthm` is defined as a `\trivlist`, with the space above controlled by `\topsep` rather than `\addvspace` (which would be *much* easier to control).  i've added this to the list of known problems to be investigated.

Comment: note if you just set parskip _lots_ of "internal paragraphs" will be affected. The `parskip` package tries to adjust at least the more common ones. Also it's more normal t allow some glue stretch in parskip to help with page breaking.

Comment: @barbarabeeton do you know whether there was any progress on this issue?

Comment: @J.C. -- I tend to doubt it.  The current package at CTAN has a user manual dated late 2017.  Updates are described in the file `...latex/required/amscls/doc/diffs-c.txt` in a TeX Live installation or on CTAN, and nothing is shown about this.  I'm retired now, so no longer have any influence.  I'd suggest nagging `tech-support@ams.org`.