# Additional space around `proof` using `parskip`

Tags: amsthm, parskip

I'm using the package `parskip` with the `amsthm` environments, and I noticed that additional spacing are added above and below the `proof` environment:

[image: here]

Any idea how to fix this? A similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339440/parskip-messes-with-the-vertical-space-between-a-theorem-and-its-proof), but never answered. Here is a the minimal code used above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[11]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `-\parskip` vertical space at the beginning of the `proof`environment with package `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[11]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, could you show *how*?

Comment: @Sigur: Sorry, a problem with my clipboard manager, and (as often) I didn't  check what I pasted. 'Tis fixed. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Ow, so short! I didn't know about `\AtBeginEnvironment`. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like an adjustment is also needed *after* the `proof`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: But what's `parskip` for, in this case? The spacing after the proof, from my point of view stresses that theorem and proof work together.

Comment: @Bernard -- The "double" skip after the proof isn't traditional in math publishing.  Your observation does make sense, and the extra space probably wouldn't be removed by a math copyeditor, but the "tombstone" and the "usual" wider-than-usual space is considered adequate to mark the end of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the additional space inserted by `proof`, which is `6pt plus 6pt`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep\z@skip % <---- changed here
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[11]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[11-12]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you're using `thmtools`, something more robust is in order, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd{\proof}{6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{\z@skip}{}{} % if not using thmtools
% with thmtools it's a bit more complicated
\expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname{6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{\z@skip}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[11]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[11-12]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! Could you explain why it is more robust? Why is it better than Bernard's or Vincent's solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `proof` environment to add a `\vspace{-\parskip}` at the beginning and at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{parskip}

\let\oldproof\proof
\let\endoldproof\endproof
\renewenvironment{proof}{%
    \vspace{-\parskip}\begin{oldproof}%
    }{%
    \end{oldproof}\vspace{-\parskip}%
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[11]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]